# Get Error "Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80" When Dockerized Web

Tags: php, docker, codeigniter, docker-compose, containers

I dockerized my PHP (Codeigniter Framework) & MySQL app successfully and First page of my website works fine on http://172.18.0.4/welcome ,  but my problem is that when I want to go to another page of my website for example about page (http://172.18.0.4/welcome/contact). I face with this error:

Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80

*Note that all of my websites page work fine on real host using Xampp.
I was try to fix htaccess like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and i set my routes.php like this,

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = false;
```

to this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['tentang'] = 'welcome/tentang';
$route['pelajaran'] = 'welcome/pelajaran';
$route['kontak'] = 'welcome/kontak';
$route['guru'] = 'welcome/guru';
$route['admin'] = 'welcome/admin';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = false;
```

Comment: Check if mod rewrite is enabled for your apache server. `a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: `welcome/contact != welcome/kontak`. Also, since you are using routes, why not access the page via `http://172.18.0.4/kontak` ?

Comment: @Vickel the result is the same, can not be accessed

Comment: @KristapsJ. I've enabled a2enmod rewrite, and it still doesn't work